# Field Values Not Displaying in PDF Using Apex and Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I am currently working on a visualforce page that is supposed to display values in PDF upon saving. But unfortunately, I am unable to fetch what I've inputted in the form. Meanwhile, here's the controller:

```
public with sharing class EnrollmentCardCX2 {

    private ApexPages.StandardController parentRecord;
    public Parent__c pg1 {get;set;}
    public Parent__c pg2 {get;set;}
    public List<Parent__c> parentlist {get;set;}
    public Student__c st1 {get;set;}
    public Student__c st2 {get;set;}
    public Student__c st3 {get;set;}
    public Student__c st4 {get;set;}
    public List<Student__c> studentlist {get;set;} 
    public Other_Children__c oc1 {get;set;}
    public Other_Children__c oc2 {get;set;}
    public Other_Children__c oc3 {get;set;}
    public Other_Children__c oc4 {get;set;}
    public List<Other_Children__c> childlist {get;set;}
    public List<Enrollment_Form__c> enrollmentList {get;set;}
    public List<Enrollment_Form__c> enrollment {get;set;}
    public List<Enrollment_Form__c> enrollmentqry {get;set;}
    public String title {get;set;}
    public Boolean Page1 {get;set;}
    public Boolean Page2 {get;set;}



    public EnrollmentCardCX2(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        //title = 'STUDENT(S) ENROLLING' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + 'OTHER CHILD(REN)';
        Page1 = true;
        Page2 = false;
        parentRecord = controller;
        pg1 = new Parent__c();
        pg2 = new Parent__c();
        parentlist = new List<Parent__c>();
        st1 = new Student__c();
        st2 = new Student__c();
        st3 = new Student__c();
        st4 = new Student__c();
        studentlist = new List<Student__c>();
        studentlist.add(st1);
        studentlist.add(st2);
        studentlist.add(st3);
        studentlist.add(st4);
        oc1 = new Other_Children__c();
        oc2 = new Other_Children__c();
        oc3 = new Other_Children__c();
        oc4 = new Other_Children__c();
        childlist = new List<Other_Children__c>();
        childlist.add(oc1);
        childlist.add(oc2);
        childlist.add(oc3);
        childlist.add(oc4);




        //parentmethod();
    }
    public class NewLine {
        public String NewLine {
            get { return '\r\n'; }
            set;
            }
    }
    public void proceed() {

        List<String> nameconcat = new List<String>();
        List<Student__c> newstudentlist = new List<Student__c>();
        List<Other_Children__c> newchildrenlist = new List<Other_Children__c>();
        enrollment = new List<Enrollment_Form__c>();
        enrollmentqry = new List<Enrollment_Form__c>();
        ApexPages.getMessages().clear();

        if(pg1.Relationship_1__c == null && pg2.Relationship_2__c == null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Please accomplish the form before proceeding'));
            return;
        }

        if(pg1.Relationship_1__c != null && pg1.Cell_Phone__c == null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Please key in required details'));
            return;
        }

        if(pg1.Relationship_1__c != null && pg1.Email__c == null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Please key in required details'));
            return;
        }

        if(pg2.Relationship_2__c != null && pg2.Cell_Phone__c == null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Please key in required details'));
            return;
        }

        if(pg2.Relationship_2__c != null && pg2.Email__c == null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Please key in required details'));
            return;
        }

        if(pg1 != null) {

            Parent__c father = new Parent__c();
            father.Relationship_1__c = pg1.Relationship_1__c != '' ? pg1.Relationship_1__c : '';
            father.Salutation__c = pg1.Salutation__c != '' ? pg1.Salutation__c : '';
            father.First_Name__c = pg1.First_Name__c != '' ? pg1.First_Name__c : '';
            father.Middle_Name__c = pg1.Middle_Name__c != '' ? pg1.Middle_Name__c : '';
            father.Last_Name__c = pg1.Last_Name__c != '' ? pg1.Last_Name__c : '';
            father.Address__c = pg1.Address__c != '' ? pg1.Address__c : '';
            father.Home_Phone__c = pg1.Home_Phone__c != '' ? pg1.Home_Phone__c : '';
            father.Cell_Phone__c = pg1.Cell_Phone__c != '' ? pg1.Cell_Phone__c : '';
            father.Email__c = pg1.Email__c != '' ? pg1.Email__c : '';
            father.Employer_Organization__c = pg1.Employer_Organization__c != '' ? pg1.Employer_Organization__c : '';
            father.Position__c = pg1.Position__c != '' ? pg1.Position__c : '';
            father.Work_Phone__c = pg1.Work_Phone__c != '' ? pg1.Work_Phone__c : '';

            if(father.Relationship_1__c != null) {
                upsert father Email__c;
                parentlist.add(father);
            }
        }

        if(pg2 != null) {

            Parent__c mother = new Parent__c();
            mother.Relationship_2__c = pg2.Relationship_2__c != '' ? pg2.Relationship_2__c : '';
            mother.Salutation__c = pg2.Salutation__c != '' ? pg2.Salutation__c : '';
            mother.First_Name__c = pg2.First_Name__c != '' ? pg2.First_Name__c : '';
            mother.Middle_Name__c = pg2.Middle_Name__c != '' ? pg2.Middle_Name__c : '';
            mother.Last_Name__c = pg2.Last_Name__c != '' ? pg2.Last_Name__c : '';
            mother.Address__c = pg2.Address__c != '' ? pg2.Address__c : '';
            mother.Home_Phone__c = pg2.Home_Phone__c != '' ? pg2.Home_Phone__c : '';
            mother.Cell_Phone__c = pg2.Cell_Phone__c != '' ? pg2.Cell_Phone__c : '';
            mother.Email__c = pg2.Email__c != '' ? pg2.Email__c : '';
            mother.Employer_Organization__c = pg2.Employer_Organization__c != '' ? pg2.Employer_Organization__c : '';
            mother.Position__c = pg2.Position__c != '' ? pg2.Position__c : '';
            mother.Work_Phone__c = pg2.Work_Phone__c != '' ? pg2.Work_Phone__c : '';

            if(mother.Relationship_2__c != null) {
                upsert mother Email__c;
                parentlist.add(mother);
            }
        }


        for(Student__c stloop : studentlist) {
            String concat = '';
            if(stloop.First_Name__c != '' && stloop.Middle_Name__c != '' && stloop.Last_Name__c != '') {
                concat = stloop.First_Name__c.deleteWhitespace() + stloop.Middle_Name__c.deleteWhitespace() + stloop.Last_Name__c.deleteWhitespace();
            }
            nameconcat.add(concat);
        }

        List<Student__c> checkStudents = [SELECT ID, Name, First_Name__c, Middle_Name__c, Last_Name__c, Student_Name__c, Grade_Level__c FROM Student__c WHERE Student_Name__c IN : nameconcat];
        Integer stnum = 0;

        /*


        //Set<Student__c> setst = new Set<Student__c>();

        //for(Student__c nameloop : studentlist) 
        for(stnum=0; stnum < studentlist.size(); stnum++) {
            for(Student__c studentloop : checkStudents) {
                if(studentlist[stnum].First_Name__c != '' && studentlist[stnum].Last_Name__c != '') {
                    system.debug('studentlist[stnum] first condition >> ' + studentlist[stnum]);
                    if(studentlist[stnum].First_Name__c != studentloop.First_Name__c && studentlist[stnum].Last_Name__c != studentloop.Last_Name__c) {
                        system.debug('studentlist[stnum] >> ' + studentlist[stnum]);
                        system.debug('studentloop >> ' + studentloop);
                        Student__c student = new Student__c();
                        student.First_Name__c = studentlist[stnum].First_Name__c != '' ? studentlist[stnum].First_Name__c : '';
                        student.Middle_Name__c = studentlist[stnum].Middle_Name__c != '' ? studentlist[stnum].Middle_Name__c : '';
                        student.Last_Name__c = studentlist[stnum].Last_Name__c != '' ? studentlist[stnum].Last_Name__c : '';
                        student.Grade_Level__c = studentlist[stnum].Grade_Level__c != null ? Integer.valueof(studentlist[stnum].Grade_Level__c) : null;
                        if(parentlist.size() > 0) {
                            for(Parent__c parentloop : parentlist) {
                                if(parentloop.Relationship_1__c != null && parentloop.Relationship_2__c == null) {
                                    student.Parent_Father__c = parentloop.id;
                                }
                                if(parentloop.Relationship_2__c != null && parentloop.Relationship_1__c == null) {
                                    student.Parent_Mother__c = parentloop.id;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        newstudentlist.add(student);
                    } else {
                        system.debug('stnum : ' + stnum + ' ' + studentlist[stnum].First_Name__c + ' >> ' + studentloop.First_Name__c);
                        studentlist.remove(stnum);
                    }
                }        
            }
        }

        if(newstudentlist.size() > 0) {
            insert newstudentlist;
        }
        */
        for(Other_Children__c other : childlist) {
            if(other.Name != '') {
                Other_Children__c newchild = new Other_Children__c();
                newchild.Name = other.Name;
                newchild.Date_of_Birth__c = other.Date_of_Birth__c;
                if(parentlist.size() > 0) {
                    for(Parent__c parentloop : parentlist) {
                        if(parentloop.Relationship_1__c != null && parentloop.Relationship_2__c == null) {
                            newchild.Father__c = parentloop.id;
                        }
                        if(parentloop.Relationship_2__c != null && parentloop.Relationship_1__c == null) {
                            newchild.Mother__c = parentloop.id;
                        }
                    }
                }
                newchildrenlist.add(newchild);
            }
        }
        if(newchildrenlist.size() > 0) {
            insert newchildrenlist;
        }
        system.debug('newstudentlist1 >> ' + newstudentlist.size() + ' ' + newstudentlist);
        for(Student__c addstudents : checkStudents) {

            newstudentlist.add(addstudents);
        }
        system.debug('newstudentlist2 >> ' + newstudentlist.size() + ' ' + newstudentlist);

        enrollment = createEnrollmentForm(newstudentlist);

        Set<ID> eid = new Set<ID>();

        for(Enrollment_Form__c loopid : enrollment) {
            eid.add(loopid.id);
        }

        enrollmentqry = [SELECT ID, Name, Student_Name__c FROM Enrollment_Form__c WHERE ID IN : eid];

        Page1 = false;
        Page2 = true;
        sendPdf();
    }

    public PageReference queryStudent() {
        system.assertequals(studentlist + ' >> ' + st1,'test');

        return null;

    }

    public List<Enrollment_Form__c> createEnrollmentForm(List<Student__c> students) {
        system.debug('students >> ' + students.size() + ' >> ' + students);
        enrollmentList = new List<Enrollment_Form__c>();

        for(Student__c loopStudent : students) {
            Enrollment_Form__c newForm = new Enrollment_Form__c();
            newForm.Student__c = loopStudent.id;
            if(parentlist.size() > 0) {
                for(Parent__c parentloop : parentlist) {
                    if(parentloop.Relationship_1__c != null && parentloop.Relationship_2__c == null) {
                        newForm.Parent_Guardian1__c = parentloop.id;
                    }
                    if(parentloop.Relationship_2__c != null && parentloop.Relationship_1__c == null) {
                        newForm.Parent_Guardian2__c = parentloop.id;
                    }
                }
            }
            enrollmentList.add(newForm);
        }
        system.debug('enrollmentList >> ' + enrollmentList.size() + ' >> ' + enrollmentList);
        if(enrollmentList.size() > 0) {
            insert enrollmentList;


        }

        return enrollmentList;
    }


    public PageReference sendPdf(){
        //public Set<ID> eid{get;set;}

        PageReference pdf = Page.EnrollmentPDFPage;
        //pdf.getParameters().put('id', enrollmentList);

        Blob body;

        try {
            body = pdf.getContent();
        }catch (VisualforceException e) {
            body = Blob.valueOf('baklushiee');
        }

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
        attach.setFileName('baklushiee.pdf');
        attach.setInline(false);
        attach.Body = body;


        List<String> newEMail = new List<String>();
        newEmail.add('latosa.gizelle@gmail.com');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setToAddresses(newEmail);
        mail.setSubject('Baklushie Sample');
        mail.setHtmlBody('Please check the attachment.');
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{ attach });


        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

        //ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Email with PDF sent to '+email));

        return null;
    }

    public class parentWrapper {

        public Parent__c parent {get;set;}

        public parentWrapper() {
            Parent__c parent = new Parent__c();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Enrollment_Form__c" extensions="EnrollmentCardCX2" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf">
    <apex:form >
         <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!enrollmentList}" var="enroll" border="2">
                <apex:column value="{!enroll.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance.

### Here's the other page calling the proceed method...

vf page: EnrollmentCardPage2

```
<apex:page standardController="Parent__c" extensions="EnrollmentCardCX2" sidebar="false" 

showHeader="false">
    <!--
    <script>
        function setRequired() {
            if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.block1.cp.cp1}').value == '' || 

document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.block1.email.email1}').value == '') {
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.block1.cp.cp1}').value = '0';
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.block1.email.email1}').value = '';
                reRenderBlock();
                }
        }
    </script>
    -->
    <style>
        #divblock {
            margin: auto;
            width: 57%;
        }
        #header {
            margin: auto;
            width: 50%;
        }
        #image {
            margin: auto;
            width: 50%;
        }
        #divresult {
            margin-top: 10%;
            margin-left: 20%;
            width: 57%;
        }
        p {
            font-size: large;
        }
        rescolumn {
            font-size: large;
        }
    </style>

    <apex:form id="theForm" rendered="{!Page1}">
        <!--INSERT BR HERE FOR LOGO-->
        <div id="header">
            <apex:sectionHeader title="    FAMILY INFORMATION SHEET AY 2015 — 2016"/>
        </div>
        <div id="image" align="center">
            <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.logo}" width="100" height="100"/>
        </div>
        <div id="divblock">
        <apex:pageBlock id="block1">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="showMsg">
                    <apex:Messages style="color: red;"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField label="Please select relationship: " value="{!

pg1.Relationship_1__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField label="Please select relationship: " value="{!

pg2.Relationship_2__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg1.Salutation__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg2.Salutation__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg1.First_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg2.First_Name__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg1.Middle_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg2.Middle_Name__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg1.Last_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg2.Last_Name__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg1.Address__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg2.Address__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg1.Home_Phone__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg2.Home_Phone__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="cp">
                <apex:inputField id="cp1" label="*Cellphone" value="{!pg1.Cell_Phone__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField label="*Cellphone" value="{!pg2.Cell_Phone__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="email">
                <apex:inputField id="email1" label="*Email" value="{!pg1.Email__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField label="*Email" value="{!pg2.Email__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg1.Employer_Organization__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg2.Employer_Organization__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg1.Position__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg2.Position__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg1.Work_Phone__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!pg2.Work_Phone__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <p>* School announcements and communication will be sent to this number and 

address.</p>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </div>
        <div id="divblock" align="center">
        <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="STUDENT(S) ENROLLING" >

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!studentlist}" var="sl" title="STUDENT(S) ENROLLING" 

width="10%">
                    <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
                        <apex:inputText value="{!sl.First_Name__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Middle Name">
                        <apex:inputText value="{!sl.Middle_Name__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                        <apex:inputText value="{!sl.Last_Name__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Grade Level">
                        <apex:inputText value="{!sl.Grade_Level__c}"/>
                        <!--
                            <apex:actionSupport action="{!queryStudent}" event="onchange" 

rerender="verified"/>
                        </apex:inputText>
                        -->
                    </apex:column>
                    <!--<apex:column id="verified" rendered="{}">Verified</apex:column> --> 
                </apex:pageBlockTable>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="OTHER CHILD(REN)" columns="4">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!childlist}" var="cl" title="OTHER CHILD(REN)">

                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        <apex:inputText value="{!cl.Name}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Date of Birth">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!cl.Date_of_Birth__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <h5>To the best of my knowledge, the information submitted on this form is true and 

correct. &nbsp;</h5>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!proceed}" title="Proceed" value="Proceed"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </div>


    </apex:form>
    <apex:form id="resultForm" rendered="{!Page2}">
        <div id="divresult">
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <p>You have now successfully accomplished the pre-enrollment form</p>
                <p>This is your reference number for each student being enrolled: </p>

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!enrollmentqry}" var="e">
                    <apex:column styleClass="rescolumn" headerValue="Name" value="{!

e.Student_Name__c}"/>
                    <apex:column styleClass="rescolumn" headerValue="Reference Number" 

value="{!e.Name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>

                <p>Please keep a copy of the reference number and present it to the Registrar</p>
                <p><b>Thank you!</b></p>
                <p>Click here to go back to the Everest Website</p>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </div>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: From where you are calling your `proceed` method?

Answer (score 1):

Your two vf pages are having different `StandardController` due to which the Extension class is being re-initiated after redirection to the 2nd page. So your list variable `enrollmentList` is having no values in the 2nd page.

You should be using same standardController in both the pages. If thats not possible let me know I will try to find other ways to pass the values to the 2nd page.